# Changing look when tapping button with layer gradient

Tags: ios, uibutton, calayer, quartz-graphics

I used this question:

[How to create a UIButton with a black gradient for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936917/how-to-create-a-uibutton-with-a-black-gradient-for-iphone)

... to set up a color gradient as the background of my button and it looks great, but when I tap the button it doesn't visibly change and give the user any feedback that they successfully tapped the button.

How can I set up a second gradient for the highlighted state or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are setting a sublayer and not providing any content to the button's views. The sublayers are drawn directly, so the UIButton doesn't think it has any content to "highlight". If you want a different effect on your button when you select it, there are three simple approaches.

One is to make two images with gradients. A pressed and normal state. This is much simpler as you can design them as you want and its a simple one line, one time implementation.

The other option is adding selectors that get called when your button gets `UIControlEventTouchDown` and whichever other [Control Event(s)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl) you want to have it switch back under.

The last simple option is to subclass UIButton and use the `UIResponder` touch methods to determine when to manually switch between the different background types.