# How to add CAGradientLayer to UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, cagradientlayer

I am trying to modify a button's look and spent a long while trying to figure out why I can not apply a gradient to it like with this simple code below:

```
[self.playButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.playButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

CAGradientLayer *gradient = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
gradient.frame = self.playButton.bounds;
gradient.position = CGPointMake(self.playButton.bounds.size.width/2, self.playButton.bounds.size.height/2);
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   (id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor,
                   (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,
                   nil];
gradient.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                      nil];

[self.playButton.layer addSublayer:gradient];
```

It executes, but nothing happens. I know the code ought to work, because many other use it and when changing the `self.playButton` to say `self.view` then it adds a beautiful red-green gradient layer to the `UIView`.

It may be worth noting that I the custom button is defined as an `IBOutlet` like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE & FIX**

When changing the button to use a scalable image instead of a gradient, I forgot to re-comment-out the gradient code (after trying [rokjarc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/653513/rokjarc)'s idea) and when changing the button's `imageView.content` to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` the gradient displayed...

```
self.playButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

So thanks [rokjarc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/653513/rokjarc) I suppose :D

Answer (score 1):

Simply change

```
self.playButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

to

```
self.playButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Just tested and it works.

Comment: Tried that also, but that doesn't work either. I wanted to apply a gradient like explained in the link below, but since neither the glossy gradient nor my red-green gradient display I am truly lost. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936917/how-to-create-a-uibutton-with-a-black-gradient-for-iphone

Comment: Seems as if the `imageView.content` mode wasn't set up properly. Changed it to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` and now it works :o